# How do you know who or what is locking a remote file?

Tags: windows, filesystems, locking, network-share

I can tell what process is holding a lock using [Unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/).

But the problem is that, when there is a lock on a file on a remote machine, Unlocker doesn't show who or what process is locking.

Is there anyway what is holding a lock on a remote file (my remote file is mapped through a network drive)?
and also how to remove the lock?

Comment: while installing unlocker, make sure you uncheck the option for ebay promos. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open up Computer Management, right click (my) Computer and click "Manage":

**System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files**

To connect to a remote machine, select "Computer Managment (Local)" in the left pane, then pull up the "**Action > Connect to another computer...**" dialog, enter the computer name, and hit ok.

You can disconnect sessions from this interface as well.

Comment: This works for now.  Seems kind of annoying to run fsmgmt.msc under different credential (runas /user:domain\user "mmc fsmgmt.msc")

Answer (score 5):

[Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can search for handle on a file

[image]

On a *remote* machine however, you want to combine [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) with [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) in order to execute Handle on the distant computer.

Comment: I use "Process Explorer" a lot on my local machine. How do you run it on a remote one?

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) from Sysinternals.

Answer (score 0):

[Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) is a great tool.

We have it on all of our Windows servers.  It will unlock the file for you and show you what is using it.

Comment: That's already what I am using and mentioned in my question...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in this, but the [openfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490961.aspx) command might do what you want.

Answer (score -3):

If you're on Unix/Linux/BSD, `lsof(8)` should do what you want.

```
drewble:~$ lsof /home/drew/.purple/cap.db 
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE    NODE NAME
pidgin  6488 drew   13u   REG   8,18 679936 9971928 /home/drew/.purple/cap.db
```

Comment: It says Windows on the first line.

Comment: It did till Joel corrected that reference to a tag