# How do you know who or what is locking a removable disk?

Tags: filesystems, locking, safe-remove

I was reading that question [How do you know who or what is locking a remote file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1948/how-do-you-know-who-or-what-is-locking-a-remote-file) and I remember that question... even in Windows7, the Windows doesn't show that program is locking the removable disk, so we cannot safely remove the hardware. There is some tool to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've used [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Microsoft (formerly Sysinternals).  You can search for the file name and it will tell you which process is holding on and you can kill the handle on the file.  The tool is also great at looking deep into your process tree.  It's free too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Windows-centric:

Uwe Sieber's [RemoveDrive](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) can do this, some of the time, even optionally suspending the indexing service to do so.

On Vista x64 I've still sometimes found it necessary to manually close *System*'s handle to the drive letter and/or the \Device\HarddiskVolumeX path RemoveDrive reports by using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s Handle viewer, however. This even after verifying it not in use by any processes or services. (I've searched for an explanation for some time.)

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember where I found it, but Unlocker for Windows has done a dandy job of finding and unlocking whatever is tying up removable disks and files (I need to delete or move).

**Edit**: Found the link again - http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/