# Run "Shared Folders" (fsmgmt.msc) as a different user

Tags: windows, network-share, runas, credentials

I am trying to run `Shared Folders` under a different domain user according to one of user's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1948/how-do-you-know-who-or-what-is-locking-a-remote-file/1976#1976) for my other question `How do you know who or what is locking a remote file?`

> runas /user:domain\user fsmgmt.msc

Even though running `fsmgmt.msc` by itself works fine,
I am not able to run it when combining with `runas`.
(domain\user <-- I am using a valid user name)

```
C:\>runas /user:domain\user fsmgmt.msc
Enter the password for domain\user:
Attempting to start fsmgmt as user "domain\user" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - fsmgmt.msc
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Is that intentional or am I supposed to put location of `fsmgmt.msc` in `PATH` environment variable?
Questions:
 - How was I able to run `fsmgmt.msc` without updating `PATH`?
 - Is it possible to `runas` a different user for `fsmgmt.msc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running MMC instead:

runas /user:domain\user "mmc fsmgmt.msc"

Comment: +Marked as Answer: Worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it was not in your path...

try:

runas /user:domain\user %systemroot%\system32\fsmgmt.msc

Comment: It was in my env. path. And I didn't know that I could invoke a command through env. variable names...  Thank you for your answer, MathewC.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing you the steps that worked via GUI

Please search for fsmgmt.msc in the search bar and open the file location by right clicking on it.

Then please try to Hold down the shift key and right click on the application/program or shortcut which you wish to open via different credential

Please refer the below article for more information
http://www.windowscage.com/how-to-run-application-as-different-user-in-windows/